# change background color of div on button click using HTML/CSS or javascript

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 4 divs , each div has few controls and one button .

How to change the backgroud color of div based on button click in that div to grey .

Comment: Do you want it to be when you click it or when you hover over it?

Comment: When i click the button in that div

Answer (score 0):

What you are going to need to do first is find all button elements.

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
```

Next, loop through the button elements and add an event listener to each button.

When a button is clicked change the parent's background color to grey.

```
this.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
```

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
for(var i=0; i<buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click",function(e) {
    this.parentElement.style.backgroundColor = "gray";
  })
}
```

```css
hr{
  margin:0px; 
  border:none;
  height:1px;
  background-color:gray;
}
```

```html
<div>
   I will change color when you click the button.
   <button>Click Me</button>
</div>
<hr/>
<div>
   I will change color too.
   <button>Click Me</button>
</div>
<hr/>
<div>
   What about me?
   <button>Click Me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I added a  the code snippet it worked , but i have hr tags between each div to draw a line so there is some space between div color and line can it be fixed or should i not use hr tag for drawing line between divs .

Comment: If you have to use the hr tag, then my snippet is updated to show how to make it work.

Comment: another issue i see is when one div element is selected , and we select  another div element , how to remove the selection of older div element selected

Answer (score 0):

Well here is a non- bootstrap solution to your quesiton:

You can find a live example [here.](https://trevorc.ca/codesample.php?script=80)

HTML:

```
<div id="1">
<button onclick="button = 1; changecolour();">Click Me</button>
</div>
<div id="2">
<button onclick="button = 2; changecolour();">Click Me</button>
</div>
<div id="3">
<button onclick="button = 3; changecolour();">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

CSS (optional ((for demo))):

```
div {

  height: 150%;

  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: lightgreen;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 4px black;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 4px black;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 4px black;
  text-align: center;
 padding: 5px;

  }
```

Javascript:

```
var button = "";
function changecolour() {

console.log(button);
document.getElementById(button).style.backgroundColor = "lightgray";

 }
```